# Nuget Dependency Management - what are my options?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, dependency-management, project.json

I have started at a new company recently and was tasked to resolve dependency management issues.

Tools:
Visual Studio Enterprise 2015

Nuget 3.x

Team Foundation Server 2012 (won't be upgrading for at least six months)

MS SQL Server 2008

Current Dependency Management solution is to use Project References (it's quite the web of confusion)

.NET FrameWork 4.0 (they won't be upgrading anytime soon - several dozen products all written in 4.0 or earlier)

I have tried to get nuget packages and dependencies to work with VS 2015 and the tools above.  The problem I run into is a common one: csproj hintpaths written to the csproj file.  If I can't get flexible versions for these dependencies life is unpleasant.

I am looking for something more flexible like Project.JSON where we can use Transitive Restore.

My first impression is I am stuck with classic csproj and hintpath hell.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

With Nuget 3 you can use project.json.  That may be the best bet here.

Thanks everyone! :D